# constructing ISO 8601 date in C++ from strings containing date and time

Tags: c++, datetime

I want to construct a ISO 8601 format date from date string and time string.
From a SOAP request, I am getting date and time in string. Date and Time are according to GMT. Now, I want to construct a date of format ISO 8601.

For e.g. I have date string = 2012-10-23 and time string = 21:30:10

And I want datetime string constructing using above two details like 2012-10-23T23:30:10.000Z

How can I do this in C++ ? Please suggest.

Comment: have you tried writing some code?

Comment: How about `date + "T" + time + "Z"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string MakeISODate( string iDate, string iTime )
{
    return iDate + "T" + iTime + "Z";
}

int main()
{
    string date = "2012-10-23";
    string time = "21:30:10";

    string isoDate = MakeISODate( date, time );
    cout << "ISO 8601 : " << isoDate << endl;
    return 0;
}
```